# ERROR in Error during template compile of 'Ng2DropdownMenu' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After reinstall package.json file using npm. I am facing error during run command **ng build --prod** as

**ERROR in Error during template compile of 'Ng2DropdownMenu'   Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called.**

Right now, as per my knowledge, Ng2DropdownMenu is not used by me in my project and also unable to find error in file or line no.

What should I do to fix it..?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run IndianRailAndroidApp4:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.27",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "angular5-social-login": "^1.0.9",
    "angularx-social-login": "^2.3.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "arrive": "^2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "chartist": "^0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "^0.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "datatables": "^1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "getstream": "^3.23.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "jvectormap": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-adsense": "^8.0.1",
    "ng2-material-dropdown": "^0.11.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.6.1",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.4.6",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.10.1",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
    "uglify-js": "^1.3.5",
    "validate": "^3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.12",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1"
  }
}
```

**app.module.js**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // this is needed!
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdsenseModule } from 'ng2-adsense';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatStepperModule,
} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule } from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin/admin-layout.component';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './layouts/auth/auth-layout.component';

import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers/auth.guard';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomePageComponent } from './api/home-page/home-page.component';

import { GenerateComponent } from './invoice/generate/generate.component';
import { SweetAlertComponent } from './components/sweetalert/sweetalert.component';

//import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
//import { CarouselHolderComponent } from './carousel/carousel-holder.component';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class MaterialModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
    AdsenseModule.forRoot({
      adClient: 'ca-pub-xxxxx',         
      adSlot: xxxxxxxxxxx                       
    }),
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    SidebarModule,
    NavbarModule,
    FooterModule, HttpClientModule//, CarouselModule , SocialLoginModule
  ],
  declarations: [RefundComponent, AdsenseAdSizeComponent,   AppComponent
  ],

  providers: [ChatService, AuthGuard, AuthenticationService, LoginService, HttpClient, DashboardService,
    //{
    //provide: AuthServiceConfig,
    //useFactory: provideConfig //,  getAuthServiceConfigs
    // }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false in your tsconfig.json file and build again then it might shed some light on the actual error